# Getting build error occurred when running npm run build

Tags: next.js

The app fetches data from local Javascript file via an api. Here is below the error and code.

> $ npm run build
>
> next-crash-course@0.1.0 build
> next build && next export
>
> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
> npx browserslist@latest --update-db
> info  - Creating an optimized production build
> info  - Compiled successfully
>
> **Build error occurred
> FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/articles failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000**
> at ClientRequest. (C:\WebTest_NextJS(Brad Traversy)\pr1\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:369:20)
> at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:462:9)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
> type: 'system',
> errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
> }
> info  - Collecting page data .npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path C:\Test_NextJS\pr1
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c next build && next export
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\MH1\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-21T02_51_47_465Z-debug.log

NOTE: in the dev mode everything work fine.
Code link: https://github.com/bradtraversy/next-crash-course

Comment: I am downloading it now. Let me try on my local PC. I will update in few minutes.

Comment: Added the solution. Please review the answer below

Answer (score 0):

When we are building with "**next export**" it will try to invoke the call to fetch the data **Pages/index.js** line 13. In Config/index.js it is expecting the API server is hosted somewhere "**https://yourwebsite.com**". As a workaround,

1. Modify "https://yourwebsite.com" to "**http://localhost:3000**" inside **Config/index.js**
2. Open one terminal and start "**npm run dev**"
3. Open 2nd terminal and execute "**npm run build**". As the API is running in localhost:3000, it will build properly.

**Config/index.js**

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://yourwebsite.com'
```

**Pages/index.js**

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/articles`)
  const articles = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      articles,
    },
  }
}
```

[image]

URL: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

[image]

Browse the link in any browser. Example: **http://localhost:3000/about**

[image]

Comment: Error occurred prerendering page "/about". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
Error: Cannot find module for page: /about

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? Could you please update your original query with the details and screen prints?

Comment: If it throws the prerendering error. Please browse that url in your browser. Example: for "/about", Open a browser and navigate to "http://localhost:3000/about". Then run "npm run build". If you get any other pre-render error, please do visit that end point. I have attached a new Image. Please review.

Comment: Thank you very much Viswanatha for your help on NextJS building static pages problem resolution , WOW, Cheer!